# Display a ListView in fragment from JsonTask

Tags: android, listview

I want to display a list view after button click on a fragment.

```
public class Price extends Fragment{
Button submit;
submit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submit);
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView lvShareSummary;
            lvShareSummary = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listviewStatement);
            new JSONTaskShare(v.getContext(), lvShareSummary).execute("http://localhost:8080/price/PriceList");

        }
    });
}
}
```

XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp">
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#eed369"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textColor="#182237"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listviewStatement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout4"
    android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Without the button click the list view is working fine. But I want to show list view after the button click.

Comment: What is `v` and where returning view from `onCreateView` ?

Comment: keep every thing relating to listview out side onclick ,just set adapter to listview inside button onclick

Comment: Where are you setting the adapter for the list?

Comment: @Santosh Shrestha can you post your full code?

Comment: Thank your Redman it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Redman for the answer

```
public class Price extends Fragment{
Button submit;
ListView lvShareSummary;
lvShareSummary = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listviewStatement);
submit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.submit);
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new JSONTaskShare(v.getContext(), lvShareSummary).execute("http://localhost:8080/price/PriceList");

    }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are newbie in android. Fragment code cannot be written like this. The child view inside fragment must be initilize with the view object we have in 
onCreateView so your code will be this:

```
public class Price extends Fragment{
Button submit;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container, false);

submit = (Button) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.submit);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView lvShareSummary;
            lvShareSummary = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listviewStatement);
            new JSONTaskShare(v.getContext(), lvShareSummary).execute("http://localhost:8080/price/PriceList");
        return fragmentView;

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<> listdata;

public class JSONTaskShare extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {


        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
            return Utility.getJSONArray(url);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {


            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject row = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    // add here your parsing result in arraylist

                   listdata.add();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
        }
    }


Create an adapter here.

public class PricelistfragmentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    Activity activity
    ArrayList<> arrayList;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public TvAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.activity = activity;
        this.arrayList = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
     // set Your view here.
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_data, null);
       // set your value here  ...

        return rowView;
    }

}


// Now in your Price Fragment set adapter value.

PricelistfragmentAdapter pricelistfragmentAdapter=new PricelistfragmentAdapter(getActivity,arrayList);
lvShareSummary.setAdapter(pricelistfragmentAdapter);
```